# angular simple tip calculator, division and addition

Tags: angularjs

This is my first attempt at a basic angular app, that calculates a tip upon tabulating.  Here is a js fiddle I made.  http://jsfiddle.net/xLc6h7w3/  I'm running into I think an issues where it isn't seeing the click and throwing an error.  I'm not sure where I am going wrong here.

```
angular.module('tipApp',[]).controller('tipController', function() {

var tipCalc = this;
tipCalc.bill = "100";
tipCalc.percent = "10";

tipCalc.calc = function() {
var getme = tipCalc.bill / tipCalc.percent;
var total = getme + tipCalc.bill;
tipCalc.results = total;
};

});
```

Here is the html

```
 <h2>Tip Calculator</h2>
    <div ng-controller="tipController as tipCalc">

      <span>Percent <input class="percent"  ng-model="tipCalc.percent" placeholder="Percent Tip" type="input"/>% of 
      <input class="bill" ng-model="tipCalc.bill" Placeholder="Bill Amount" type="input" /> Bill</span>

<br/><br/>
        <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Tabulate" ng-click="tipCalc.calc()"/>
<br/><br/>
<h3>Money Needed with Tip</h3>

<input class="moneyNeeded" type="input" ng-model="results" />


    </div>
```

Comment: Definitely check where your reference for the moneyNeeded (i.e. ng-model="tipCalc.results"). Also, don't forget about strings vs numbers (i.e. you have to tell it to parseFloat

     var getme = parseFloat(tipCalc.bill) / parseFloat(tipCalc.percent);
     var total = parseFloat(getme) + parseFloat(tipCalc.bill);

Comment: weird it appears to be in better shape now except when I try 20% my results are way off.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `controllerAs` syntax you should use alias `tipCalc` before using any variable of controller.

**Markup**

```
<input class="moneyNeeded" type="input" ng-model="tipCalc.results" />
```

**Code**

```
 tipCalc.calc = function () {
     //you you should handle some sort of error before converting an value to integer
     //otherwise it would be shown as NaN
     //you could use parseFloat if calculation gonna be in decimal.
     var getme = parseInt(tipCalc.bill) / parseInt(tipCalc.percent);
     var total = parseInt(getme) + parseInt(tipCalc.bill);
     tipCalc.results = total;
 };
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5cjq5vx3/)

Answer (score 0):

You're using controllerAs, so you need to specify $scope variables with tipCalc

## HTML

```
<input class="moneyNeeded" type="input" ng-model="tipCalc.results" />
```

## JavaScript

```
angular.module('tipApp', []).controller('tipController', function() {

    var tipCalc = this;
    tipCalc.bill = "100";
    tipCalc.percent = "10";
    tipCalc.results = 0;

    tipCalc.calc = function() {
        tipCalc.results = (tipCalc.bill / tipCalc.percent) + tipCalc.bill;
    };

});
```